# WPF binding value of Binding property

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an image with priority binding set like this:

```xaml
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <PriorityBinding>
            <Binding Path="Image" IsAsync="True" Mode="OneWay"/>
            <Binding Path="DefaultImage" Mode="OneWay" />
        </PriorityBinding>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

What I want to do is to control `IsAsync` of first binding dynamically, something like this:

```xaml
<Binding Path="Image" IsAsync="{Binding AsyncImagesEnabled}" Mode="OneWay"/>
```

But of course that can't be done because `IsAsync` is not dependency property. I've tried to use attached properties, but that fails because you can't convert `Binding` class to `DependencyObject`. Any ideas how to solve this?

**Workaround Edit:**
So currently I use following workaround. I use `StaticResource` (since dynamic can't be used for the reasons mentioned above.

```xaml
<Binding Path="Image" IsAsync="{StaticResource AsyncImagesEnabled}" Mode="OneWay"/>
```

And then I create that resource at application startup:

```c#
Resources.Add("AsyncImagesEnabled", config.AsyncImageLoading);
```

This means that user has to restart application to apply the change, but I can live with that for now.

Comment: Why would you want to do that at all? IsAsync usually makes no sense in a Binding to a property of type ImageSource, because derived classes like BitmapImage already support asynchronous loading scenarios.

Comment: I have a big list of images in my app and I want to give users an option to choose between smooth scrolling (when IsAsync is enabled) and no "pop-in" of images in case they have slow HDD and it takes a while for images to appear when async is on (in that case IsAsync would be disabled).

Comment: Create your own dependency property that would just set `IsAsync` based on provided value

Comment: @ASpirin I can't do that because `Binding` is not `DependecyObject`, so I can't add dependency property to it.